# How to draw Sprites in different methods libgdx

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx, 2d

Hi i created a button in my create method. I added an addlistener to the button and an inputevent. However how can i render a sprite in the create method where if the button is touch. A sprite is drawn how can i do that ?/

```
 public void create () {
    buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button");
    buttonStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("buttonpressed");
    buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("buttonpressed");
    buttonStyle.font = font;
    button = new TextButton("START", buttonStyle);

    stage.addActor(button);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
     button.addListener(new InputListener(){    
         @Override
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button ){
            drawTile(200,50);
                return true;
            }
        });

    // method used to draw a sprite when passing certain coordinates 
    public void drawTile(int x , int y){

      spriteBatch.draw(sprite, x  , y   );
      }

public void render () {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(background, 0, 0);
    drawGrid();
    spriteBatch.draw(startButton, 0, 0);
   stage.draw();

   spriteBatch.end()



}
```

Comment: I am using Screen-2D to build a button. I want give the button a function when it is click a sprite will be drawn how can i do this. This isn't all all my code but enough to show what am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I have a manager for my entities to control situations like this (not sure if best approach), you will have to modulate your code.

First, I have an abstract class `Entity` that will be parent of all my entities in my game, so if I have **enemies** or **player** for example, I will have 2 classes `Enemy` and `Player` that will extend from `Entity`. This abstract class have (with other things) two principal methods, `update()` and `render()`:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    ...
    public abstract void update(float delta); // <- to move, collisions, blablabla
    public abstract void render(SpriteBatch spritebatch); // <- to draw
    ...
}
```

By having this, you just need a some-kind-of-manager to update properly your entities, a very VERY simple one is the following:

```
public class EntityManager{
    // A list of ALL your entities in your game...
    private static Array<Entity> myEntityList = new Array<Entity>();

    /**
     * A very simple add method... This is what you will call when you touch
     * your button.
     */
    public static void add(Entity newEntity){
        myEntityList.add(newEntity);
    }

    public static void update(float delta) {
        // Take care of those entities that are being updated or expired!
        ...
        // Update each of my entities
        for(Entity e : myEntityList){
            e.update(delta); // <- I'll update all my entities
        }
        ...
    }

    public static void render(SpriteBatch spritebatch){
        // draw each of my entities
        for(Entity e : myEntityList){
            e.render(spritebatch); // <- I'll draw all my entities
        }
    }

    // dispose and other things are here too (omitted for simplicity)
}
```

Because this class is  a bunch of statics methods, you just need to call the `update()` and `render()` method in your main class without instantiate it...

```
@Override
public void render(float delta){
    // code here
    ...
    EntityManager.update(delta); // <- Update all your entities
    spritebatch.begin();
    EntityManager.render(spritebatch); // <- Draw all your entities
    spritebatch.end();
    ...
    // more code here
}
```

And for the last, wherever you have your button listener...

```
myButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (...) {
            Gdx.app.log("I'll add an entity");
            EntityManager.add(new Enemy()); // <--- here, new entity added!
            // EntityManager.add(new OtherEnemy()); <-- other example
            return false;
    }

    public void touchUp (...) {
            Gdx.app.log("blah");
    }
});
```

I have to omit a lot of code but I hope you get the idea. By doing this, you will have more control of all your entities in your game. I repeat, not sure if best approach but works for me.